# Transform dataframe in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df<- structure(list(year = structure(c(72L, 2L, 13L, 24L, 35L, 46L, 
57L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 69L), .Label = c("day", 
"id.1.00000", "id.10.0000", "id.11.0000", "id.12.0000", "id.13.0000", 
"id.14.0000", "id.15.0000", "id.16.0000", "id.17.0000", "id.18.0000", 
"id.19.0000", "id.2.00000", "id.20.0000", "id.21.0000", "id.22.0000", 
"id.23.0000", "id.24.0000", "id.25.0000", "id.26.0000", "id.27.0000", 
"id.28.0000", "id.29.0000", "id.3.00000", "id.30.0000", "id.31.0000", 
"id.32.0000", "id.33.0000", "id.34.0000", "id.35.0000", "id.36.0000", 
"id.37.0000", "id.38.0000", "id.39.0000", "id.4.00000", "id.40.0000", 
"id.41.0000", "id.42.0000", "id.43.0000", "id.44.0000", "id.45.0000", 
"id.46.0000", "id.47.0000", "id.48.0000", "id.49.0000", "id.5.00000", 
"id.50.0000", "id.51.0000", "id.52.0000", "id.53.0000", "id.54.0000", 
"id.55.0000", "id.56.0000", "id.57.0000", "id.58.0000", "id.59.0000", 
"id.6.00000", "id.60.0000", "id.61.0000", "id.62.0000", "id.63.0000", 
"id.64.0000", "id.65.0000", "id.66.0000", "id.67.0000", "id.68.0000", 
"id.69.0000", "id.7.00000", "id.70.0000", "id.8.00000", "id.9.00000", 
"month"), class = "factor"), `2012` = c(1, 76.1, 38.1, 88.6, 
132.5, 241.9, 343.2, 343.2, 291.7, 82.8, 17.6, 17.6, 17.5, 17.6, 
17.6, 17.6, 17.5, 18.7, 20.4, 17.3, 16.8, 67.6, 66.2, 16.8, 16.8, 
16.8, 121.8, 0.1, 99.9, 101.5, 52, 81.6, 68.5, 37.6, 46.2, 23.4, 
31, 55.7, 24, 384.8, 53.3, 22.7, 18.6, 25.4, 42.9, 16.5, 75, 
69.7, 43.2, 90.9, 18.5, 53.1, 21.6, 66.9, 40.8, 153.3, 47.2, 
98.6, 75.8, 141.6, 9.8, 12.7, 12.7, 69.2, 18.3, 359, 153.4, 24.3, 
24.3, 24.3, 7.9), `2012` = c(2, 104.6, 41.4, 24.8, 25, 299.3, 
181.6, 181.6, 223, 49.1, 9.3, 9.3, 8.7, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 8.7, 9.6, 
5.2, 3.9, 4.4, 29.2, 30.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 49.1, 7.2, 27.7, 12.7, 
20.5, 15.2, 19.7, 4.8, 35.7, 31.6, 6, 7.4, 2.1, 452.5, 43.2, 
92.8, 62, 17.3, 8.4, 14.2, 94.5, 60.1, 28.3, 18.8, 0, 49.1, 11.4, 
47.7, 44.6, 73.3, 23, 62.9, 30.5, 95, 45.8, 42.4, 42.4, 31.1, 
33.8, 340, 63.8, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 8.3), `2012` = c(3, 196.1, 
75.8, 26.7, 27.5, 410.1, 287.8, 287.8, 254.9, 56.9, 24.6, 24.6, 
20.8, 24.6, 24.6, 24.6, 20.8, 13.3, 21.3, 20.7, 22.9, 41.2, 42.9, 
22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 63.4, 34.1, 15.6, 11.1, 8.5, 10.4, 8.1, 35.6, 
27, 20.2, 18.1, 33.7, 45.3, 363.2, 32.3, 28.9, 14.6, 10.7, 45.6, 
18.3, 159.2, 51.7, 33.6, 17.5, 52.8, 62.9, 20.5, 28.3, 21, 28.1, 
24.3, 48.1, 41.6, 179.6, 2.7, 36.9, 36.9, 59, 41.4, 349, 59.2, 
21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 31.7), `2012` = c(4, 27.5, 45.4, 87.6, 123.1, 
290.6, 99.9, 99.9, 103.9, 33.7, 24.9, 24.9, 21.2, 24.9, 24.9, 
24.9, 21.2, 15.6, 57.2, 48.3, 43.6, 51.8, 54.8, 43.6, 43.6, 43.6, 
67.8, 58.6, 26.5, 25.5, 26.6, 19.3, 24.2, 24.8, 43.8, 39.2, 67.4, 
190.8, 121.5, 462.7, 0, 79.8, 45.8, 23.6, 161.1, 120.7, 119.8, 
44.4, 62, 66.4, 63.1, 68, 19.4, 50.8, 63.7, 122.9, 119.3, 103.1, 
81.3, 97.1, 14.8, 36.6, 36.6, 35.3, 82.3, 313, 75.1, 18.6, 18.6, 
18.6, 67.1), `2012` = c(5, 72.5, 102.2, 66.2, 70.8, 214.6, 73.4, 
73.4, 69.7, 72.1, 35.5, 35.5, 31, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 31, 24.1, 
67.8, 67, 60.1, 82.3, 86, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 48.5, 62.7, 53.4, 
54.2, 42.9, 55.6, 19, 0, 47.5, 26.1, 91.5, 32.5, 51.6, 389.3, 
0, 30.5, 10.9, 40.4, 89.5, 62.9, 123.9, 71.2, 151.6, 69.4, 101.4, 
49.8, 27.1, 35, 19.6, 72.6, 31.7, 120, 143.3, 54.2, 8.8, 3.6, 
3.6, 33.3, 143.8, 221, 59.5, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 314.6), `2012` = c(6, 
101.8, 124.8, 117, 136.3, 194.3, 142.1, 142.1, 135.2, 87.9, 75.2, 
75.2, 72.7, 75.2, 75.2, 75.2, 72.7, 61.5, 101.8, 108.6, 103.7, 
125.8, 131.9, 103.7, 103.7, 103.7, 52.8, 200.5, 81.9, 103.6, 
68.5, 83.2, 65.2, 1.2, 79.6, 64.7, 76.3, 73, 35.6, 238.4, 0, 
13.6, 0.1, 26.7, 65, 17.5, 169.5, 36.3, 71.8, 86.4, 3.1, 117.9, 
23.6, 61.6, 93.3, 143.1, 122.6, 167, 96.7, 77.6, 33.5, 0, 0, 
94.8, 160, 220, 89.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 399.9), `2012` = c(7, 
62.8, 68.9, 108.8, 180.2, 189.2, 51.8, 51.8, 46.2, 50.2, 68.7, 
68.7, 64.1, 68.7, 68.7, 68.7, 64.1, 60, 107.8, 101.8, 90.7, 40.6, 
41.7, 90.7, 90.7, 90.7, 53.8, 289.2, 72.9, 86.2, 119.4, 66.8, 
59.4, 0, 97.5, 67.3, 63.4, 47.7, 33, 142, 0, 35.8, 17.9, 66.1, 
25.6, 0.6, 246.8, 109.1, 122.4, 89.7, 2.6, 44.6, 8, 91, 60.2, 
100.8, 99.8, 59.2, 112.9, 10.2, 66.5, 0.8, 0.8, 64.5, 131.4, 
173, 50.4, 7.3, 7.3, 7.3, 590), `2012` = c(8, 98.2, 81.1, 40.7, 
48.9, 61.8, 33.5, 33.5, 27.1, 73.7, 80.9, 80.9, 82.1, 80.9, 80.9, 
80.9, 82.1, 82, 75.9, 78.3, 75.5, 99.3, 97.2, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 
44.2, 240.8, 46.8, 44.7, 51.4, 45.2, 46, 2.6, 43.8, 23.5, 10.6, 
21.1, 40.1, 91.6, 0, 23.5, 18.6, 34.8, 48, 36.2, 124.6, 153.4, 
146.6, 87.2, 12.4, 98, 60.6, 69.1, 118.4, 115.1, 43.6, 108.1, 
117.8, 0, 5.8, 13.9, 13.9, 57.4, 79, 165, 67.5, 60, 60, 60, 357
), `2012` = c(9, 23.9, 38.9, 53.2, 60.9, 44.2, 17.3, 17.3, 17.4, 
54.2, 45.6, 45.6, 43.6, 45.6, 45.6, 45.6, 43.6, 44.8, 30.8, 27.2, 
27.2, 79.2, 84.3, 27.2, 27.2, 27.2, 95.1, 125.9, 42.7, 30.8, 
27.4, 43.1, 35.5, 49.2, 64.4, 22.5, 38.6, 60.6, 67.1, 20.3, 0, 
69, 9, 131.8, 56.1, 58.2, 272.8, 163.3, 198.6, 50.9, 67.1, 75.6, 
85.3, 72.4, 63.5, 126.9, 63.2, 118.7, 112, 0.2, 32.8, 10.3, 10.3, 
48.2, 30.2, 169, 125.8, 87, 87, 87, 512.9), `2012` = c(10, 81.6, 
29.2, 112.8, 119.8, 29.1, 330.5, 330.5, 295.4, 111, 60.3, 60.3, 
54.9, 60.3, 60.3, 60.3, 54.9, 43.8, 53.6, 63.8, 67.7, 84.4, 87.8, 
67.7, 67.7, 67.7, 166.6, 47.3, 38.3, 39.2, 44.2, 33, 46.6, 40.6, 
92.5, 60.3, 84.4, 122.7, 184.9, 24.1, 2.1, 48.4, 22.5, 81.8, 
111.3, 148.3, 119.7, 120, 142.3, 91.8, 150.6, 108.9, 55.9, 65.6, 
69.2, 135.9, 110.7, 114.6, 100, 103.4, 28.2, 38.4, 38.4, 127.2, 
87, 203, 172, 53.8, 53.8, 53.8, 258.7), `2012` = c(11, 92.3, 
60.8, 41.8, 68.3, 43.6, 284.6, 284.6, 276.4, 45.9, 23.7, 23.7, 
21.4, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 21.4, 17.1, 27.2, 26.5, 26.5, 33.4, 36.8, 
26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 31.8, 43.9, 67.4, 46.6, 69.8, 62.5, 40.3, 68.2, 
38.8, 54.6, 39.2, 81.9, 66.7, 73.1, 56.9, 177.4, 194.8, 136.5, 
184.8, 183.7, 126.6, 158.5, 200.9, 37.2, 238.5, 84.3, 51.5, 48, 
56.3, 103.3, 101, 20.8, 39.4, 161.3, 2.6, 9, 9, 37.6, 33.5, 223, 
120.2, 49.6, 49.6, 49.6, 54.7), `2012` = c(12, 34, 36.5, 156.7, 
195.4, 132.6, 310.4, 310.4, 271.8, 87.6, 15.3, 15.3, 13.2, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 13.2, 10.3, 17.5, 15.8, 14.8, 77.5, 74.5, 14.8, 14.8, 
14.8, 122.4, 5.1, 81.1, 74.5, 58.7, 69.1, 55.8, 3.3, 48.1, 33.3, 
83.9, 173.5, 30.4, 169.4, 41.7, 86.6, 67.9, 36.3, 58.8, 121.9, 
100.7, 163.3, 155.5, 135.4, 255.8, 60, 18.7, 67.9, 57.8, 150.3, 
136.2, 109.2, 123.3, 179.5, 35.3, 92.4, 92.4, 71.4, 50.5, 237, 
135.4, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 1.1)), .Names = c("year", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to transform my dataframe using the R package `dplyr`. So far, year and month are in rows but I want them in columns. Basically I want a dataframe with a column containing the IDs, one with year, one with month and one with the values. 
The structure will look like this with an ID column additional.

```
df2<-structure(list(YEAR = c(1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L), MONTH = 1:10, PRCP = c(46.3, 20.7, 
101.3, 27.2, 67.5, 34.1, 12, 95.4, 17, 31.8)), .Names = c("YEAR", 
"MONTH", "PRCP"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can post the sample output you desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) / [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) combination and [magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr) (for convenience).

```
Vectorize(require)(package = c("tidyr",        # Data manipulation
                               "dplyr",        # Data manipulation
                               "magrittr"      # Reverse pipe
),
char = TRUE)

dfTr <- df %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value, convert = TRUE, -year) %>% 
  setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(year, key, value)
```

You can ad the following syntax to obtain one `id` column:

```
  # Unite is optional as it will generate one ID column
  unite(year_month, key, year)
```

which would produce:

```
        year  key value
1      month 2012   1.0
2 id.1.00000 2012  76.1
3 id.2.00000 2012  38.1
```

---

## With exclusion

Sample approach excluding that `month` row:

```
dfTr2 <- df %>%
  setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(year != "month") %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, convert = TRUE, -year) %>% 
  select(year, key, value) %>% 
  unite(year_month, key, year) %>% 
  mutate(year_month = gsub("X","",year_month))
```

### Cleaning month value

It crossed my mind that you may want to use the month figure, a small example below extracts the relevant digit:

```
library(stringr)
dfTr3 <- df %>%
  setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(year != "month") %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, convert = TRUE, -year) %>% 
  select(year, key, value) %>% 
  unite(year_month, key, year) %>% 
  mutate(year_month = gsub("X","",year_month)) %>% 
  mutate(month = gsub(".", "", str_extract_all(string = year_month, 
                                 pattern = "\\.\\d{1,2}\\."), 
         fixed = TRUE))
```

which produces:

```
> head(dfTr3, n = 2)
       year_month value month
1 2012_id.1.00000  76.1     1
2 2012_id.2.00000  38.1     2
```

Comment: I was also jumping through this route.  But, I think the first row is month, so, it may be better to extract that row separately and then do the `gather` on the rest of the rows.  later create a column with `the first row.

Comment: @akrun Wasn't sure to me how to approach it so decided to include it just to avoid the potential information loss. In effect it would boil down to applying `filter` at some stage.

Answer (score 3):

Your data is in an odd form; it appears that you have two header rows, which is not something supported in an R data frame.  Most likely there was something wrong with the initial import, but I can see what it is you are trying to do.

My solution would be to first fix up the data frame so that it shows what we want, which is for the headers to be the combination of the current headers (year) and the first row (month)

```
> paste(names(df), df[1,])
 [1] "year 72" "2012 1"  "2012 2"  "2012 3"  "2012 4"  "2012 5"  "2012 6"
 [8] "2012 7"  "2012 8"  "2012 9"  "2012 10" "2012 11" "2012 12"
```

That looks good (except for "year 72", which we'll fix up later), so lets set it:

```
> names(df) <- paste(names(df), df[1,])
> df %>% head
     year 72 2012 1 2012 2 2012 3 2012 4 2012 5 2012 6 2012 7 2012 8 2012 9
1      month    1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0
3 id.1.00000   76.1  104.6  196.1   27.5   72.5  101.8   62.8   98.2   23.9
4 id.2.00000   38.1   41.4   75.8   45.4  102.2  124.8   68.9   81.1   38.9
```

Now let's get rid of that first row

```
> df <- tail(df, -1)
> head(df)
      year 72 2012 1 2012 2 2012 3 2012 4 2012 5 2012 6 2012 7 2012 8 2012 9
3  id.1.00000   76.1  104.6  196.1   27.5   72.5  101.8   62.8   98.2   23.9
4  id.2.00000   38.1   41.4   75.8   45.4  102.2  124.8   68.9   81.1   38.9
```

Now we can use `tidyr`, a companion package to `dplyr` for reshaping data frames, to put it into the desired form.

```
> require(tidyr)
> df %>% gather(date, value, -`year 72`) %>% head
       year 72    date value
1   id.1.00000  2012 1  76.1
2   id.2.00000  2012 1  38.1
3   id.3.00000  2012 1  88.6
4   id.4.00000  2012 1 132.5
5   id.5.00000  2012 1 241.9
```

From here, we can use `separate` to break the "date" column into "year" and "month" columns.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick!

```
rownames(df) <- seq(length=nrow(df))
colnames(df)[2:13] <- c(1:12)
tmp <- melt(df[2:nrow(df),],id = c('year'))
colnames(tmp) <- c('id','Month','Value')
library(sqldf)
sqldf("Select * from tmp order by id")
```